# Does migration count as a question for maximum 6 posts a day?

Tags: support, migration, rate-limiting

If a question is migrated from a different SE to MSE, does it 
 count as a question for maximum 6 questions a day?

In particular, I want to request migration of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122545/if-a-r-v-x-a-ex-a to MSE, but I will hit the quota for today.

Comment: You mean 6 questions a day, I assume.

Comment: yes.   questions.

Comment: The UTC day is over in 30 minutes...

Comment: I remember it works by counting within the past 24 hours, not a calender day accoridng to some time zone. @just.

Comment: Ah yes, that is right. Well, my suggestion is to get that post migrated, so we can find the answer experimentally.

Comment: Not if I can't ask any more questions "today". @just. The best is that someone could answer my qeustion at stat.se, I hope. It is really about real analysis.

Comment: Come on, make a sacrifice for scientific progress.

Comment: I don't know SE sites themselves are science @just. Come on, answer my question on Stat.SE for enlightening a poor soul.

Comment: Are your questions so urgent that you can't wait a few hours? These restrictions are here for a reason... Anyway if these migrated posts do *not* count as I will open a feature-request question to make them count. It would be too easy to post questions in obviously wrong SE sites and get them migrated to work around the restriction.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Your comment is irrelevant and nonconstructive to this post and offensive. Did you see that I posted on other SE sites in order to avoid the quota?

Comment: I'm not saying that this is what you did, but I'm saying that this is a way that some people could abuse the system. I find my comment very on-topic, and if by "nonconstructive" you mean that I don't give an answer to your question, well, that's why I made a comment and not an answer.